# Does VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation output softmax probabilities? If so, how to extract top values?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, coreml

I'm trying to get my first image classification model working, however,
`VNClassificationObservation` isn't working, while 
`VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` is.

Here is some info about my model:

```
MLModelDescription: MLModelDescription inputDescriptionsByName: {

"input_1__0" = "input_1__0 : Image (Color, 299 x 299)";

} outputDescriptionsByName: {

    "output_node0__0" = "output_node0__0 : MultiArray (MLMultiArrayDataTypeDouble, 43)";

} predictedFeatureName: (null)
```

According to the docs:

```
VNClassificationObservation

This type of observation results from performing a VNCoreMLRequest image
analysis with a Core ML model whose role is classification (rather than 
prediction or image-to-image processing).
Vision infers that an MLModel object is a classifier model if that model 
predicts a single feature. 
That is, the model's modelDescription object has a non-nil value for its 
predictedFeatureName property.
```

At first I assumed when the docs says "prediction", they are referring to regression type model with a value prediction. But now I'm thinking they are referring to softmax prediction probabilities? Thus  VNClassificationObservation doesn't output softmax prediction probabilities.

Now,

```
VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation:

Overview
This type of observation results from performing a VNCoreMLRequest image analysis with a Core ML model whose role is prediction rather than classification or image-to-image processing.

Vision infers that an MLModel object is a predictor model if that model predicts multiple features. You can tell that a model predicts multiple features when its modelDescription object has a nil value for its predictedFeatureName property, or when it inserts its output in an outputDescriptionsByName dictionary.
```

I'm confused by the wording. Does this mean multiple input, multi-output model?
Not classification, but prediction, is a also little confusing, but I'm assuming 
softmax probs due to the output I'm getting.

When I run the code below I get:

```
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { [weak self] request, error in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation],
                let topResult = results.first else {
                    fatalError("unexpected result type from VNCoreMLRequest")
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                print("topResult!", topResult)

                //print(model.debugDescription.outputDescriptionsByName)
            }
        }
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        do {

            try handler.perform([request])

        } catch {print(error)}
```

I get back bunch of values:

```
topResult! Optional(<VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation: 
0x1c003f0c0> C99BC0A0-7722-4DDC-8FB8-C0FEB1CEEFA5 1 "MultiArray : Double 43 
vector

[ 0.02323521859943867,0.03784361109137535,0.0327669121325016,0.02373981475830078,0.01920632272958755,0.01511944644153118,0.0268220379948616,0.00990589614957571,0.006585873663425446,0.02727104164659977,0.02337176166474819,0.0177282840013504,0.01582957617938519,0.01962342299520969,0.0335112139582634,0.01197215262800455,0.04638960584998131,0.0546870082616806,0.008390620350837708,0.02519697323441505,0.01038128975778818,0.02463733218610287,0.05725555866956711,0.02852404117584229,0.01987413503229618,0.02478211745619774,0.01224409975111485,0.03397252038121223,0.02300941571593285,0.02020683139562607,0.03740271925926208,0.01999092660844326,0.03210178017616272,0.02830206602811813,0.01122485008090734,0.01071082800626755,0.02285266295075417,0.01730070635676384,0.009790488518774509,0.01149104069918394,0.03331543132662773,0.01211327593773603,0.0193191897124052]" (1.000000))
```

If these are indeed softmax probabilities, how would I go about getting the index for max value? I can't seem to use `.count` or similar array methods.

I tried to cast it as an array, but both of these didn't work 
l

```
let values  = topResult.featureValue as Array! (Can't convert...coercion)
let values = topResult as Array!
```

If these are NOT softmax values/probabilities, then would I go about getting the 
 prob. values. I'm trying to get the indices of the top 3 softmax probs.

Thank you.

!!!UPDATE!!!!!!!!:

Attempting this within function:
    var localPrediction: String?
    let topResult = results.first?.featureValue.multiArrayValue

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { () in
            var max_value : Float32 = 0
            for i in 0..<topResult!.count{
                if max_value < topResult![i].floatValue{
                    max_value = topResult![i].floatValue
                    localPrediction = String(i)}

                                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your model is a classifier, i.e. a `NeuralNetworkClassifier` in the mlmodel file, then the output is `VNClassificationObservation` objects.

When your model is not a classifier, i.e. a `NeuralNetwork` or `NeuralNetworkRegressor` then the output is one or more `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` objects that contain the output from your final layer.

So if you expect softmax output in the `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` then you need to make sure your model has a softmax as its final layer.

To get the index and value of the maximum element, use:

```
func argmax(_ array: UnsafePointer<Double>, count: Int) -> (Int, Double) {
  var maxValue: Double = 0
  var maxIndex: vDSP_Length = 0
  vDSP_maxviD(array, 1, &maxValue, &maxIndex, vDSP_Length(count))
  return (Int(maxIndex), maxValue)
}
```

To use this, first cast the MLMultiArray's `dataPointer` to an `UnsafePointer<Double>` and then call the `argmax()` function:

```
let featurePointer = UnsafePointer<Double>(OpaquePointer(features.dataPointer))
let (maxIndex, maxValue) = argmax(featurePointer, 43)
```

Comment: Hi Matthijis, sorry to bother you, by my model's final output is supposed to be a softmax layer. However in Python, I would use methods to extract the max value as well as it's indice and translate the indice to its label name.  Here I'm currently interested in doing something similar, but I can't seem to extract the index of the max value of `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` data type. Thank you.

Comment: The `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` object contains a `MLFeatureValue` object that contains an `MLMultiArray` object (in its `multiArrayValue` property). This `MLMultiArray` will contain the output from your final layer. In your case this appears to be a vector of 43 values. You can now loop through these values to find the maximum one.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my OP with your suggestion. Please see last portion(`EDIT!!!!`) if it's not too much trouble. Is that the cleanest way to do so? I only have experience with Python and numpy; in numpy we used built-in methods to find max indices.

Comment: That looks OK and it should work just fine. Personally, I would use `vDSP_maxviD()` from Accelerate framework which is similar to argmax from Numpy. Added example code to my answer above.